# Refinement panel with content type does not show all content types

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, refinement-panel

I followed this tutorial
http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/01/create-a-content-type-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-2010.html#comment-23134

It was not working alone, so I had to add the basic5: text to the managed property to make it work, as explained here:
http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/01/refining-on-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010/

Number of categories to display I put it in 10.

I changed the xml to this:

```
<Category Title="Content Type"
 Description="The content type of the item"
 Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"
 MetadataThreshold="0"
 NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"
 MaxNumberOfFilters="0"
 SortBy="Frequency"
 SortDirection="Descending"
 SortByForMoreFilters="Name"
 SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"
 ShowMoreLink="True"
 MappedProperty="ContentTypeRefinement"
 MoreLinkText="show more"
 LessLinkText="show fewer"/>
```

I ran a full crawl.
After editing the webpart. I try a different few searches but it behaves not normal in my opinion.

For example there is an image called WelcomeImage, if I search for that, 
1. Shouldnt I get a Image content type on the left?

If I search the word site: there are many results, but I only see 2 content types, discussion board, and a custom content type. What about subsites? Arent subsite content types?

What about if my keyword matches the name of a list or the name of a subsite?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that all I did its working fine. I was just a little bit confused.

A list by itself does not belong to a content type.
The list items Does.

A website by itself does not belong to a content type
The webpages does.

In this order of ideas, if I create items in discussion boards, events, tasks, documents library, pages library, etc.

And then I search for them I will see the content type refinement working pretty well.

**I was thinking that all search results should belong to a content type, but I was wrong in that concept.**

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to run across [this link](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/01/refining-on-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010/) which may answer your question.  Basically says that the "ContentType" managed property is not set to "Retrievable" and recommends adding your own managed property.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: Sorry about that -> Hadn't had my coffee yet!  Totally missed that comment in your original post.